# Is there any way to auto run some code in DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have some DLL from third party that I need to license. It has some method that I must call from my own DLL. My DLL is referenced in couple of projects and I don't want to make changes to every hoster. Is there any method that I can use within my DLL which will call some method in my DLL? Like add some static class or constructor but without explicit call to that class from hosters? I am not sure if I am explaining it clearly. Please ask questions if needed.

```
ThirdPartyType license = new ThirdPartyType();
license.Load("license.xml");
```

This is a piece of licensing code that I want to place in my DLL and call it within the same DLL.

Comment: A static constructor on the class that customers use should do.

Comment: You want this code to be executed from all assemblies that reference your own dll?

Comment: @Maarten, yes but I mean without explicit call to my dll... I don't want to change every host application and want to call it somehow on domain load or ... I don;t know how if that possible at all.

Comment: You will either have to add that dll as reference in visual studio, or you will have to specify file and assembly name while loading using reflection. Can't think of any other way around.

Comment: @TomasSmagurauskas, my DLL is referenced in many host applications and I know that I can run this licensing code in Main() method of host app or in App_Start in web app. Just wonder if there is a method to run that within the DLL itself.

Comment: As Marteen already mentioned place a static constructor within your own assembly that gets automatically called when any host is trying to use the type this constructor is defined in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the low level, the *runtime* supports  "module initializers". However, C# does not provide any way of implementing them, so the closest you can manage is a static constructor ("type initializer") or just a regular constructor.

However, it is probably a bad idea to hook your licencing into either a module initializer or a type initializer, as you don't know when they will run, and it could  impact code that *wasn't going to access your lib*. It is somewhat frowned upon to take someone's  app down because your licensing code decided it was unhappy - *especially* if your library wasn't actively  being invoked at the time.

As such: I suggest the most appropriate place to do this is in either a constructor, or a post-construction `Initialize(...)` method (with the tool refusing to work unless supplied with valid details).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suspected that is impossible.